# Javascript jQuery post()/get() JSON object as closure function before document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, closures, dom-events

I'm trying to figure out what the best way to handle a JSON object that I need to post/get when the document is ready so I can then run over another function that builds out the DOM based on said JSON object. This object is also something that updates every 30 seconds to a minute.

My initial thought was to build it out as a closure. i.e.:

```
var myJSONobject = $.post(uri, function(data){return data;});
```

however the function I run when the for document ready, and functions I base on click events don't recognize the object as being valid. It returns a JSON object, and I've used `jsonlint.com` to confirm that the object format is valid. So I am thinking its in how I am handling the string of events. Where the object though it may be legit is being rendered after the document ready thus breaking the functionality in a sense. Cause if I take the same object it spits out and hard code it in as a variable. the code I've been working on works fine. So now I am trying to figure out whats my best approach to handling this so one, my script doesn't break prematurely. and two find out if trying to adapt this as a closure the way I am is the right way? Whats a good practice logic in this type of scenario? Should I load the JSON object into a hidden div somewhere or text area and pass it through that or what?

Comment: Your AJAX request returns a JSON object and your callback function returns a JSON object, but your `myJSONobject` variable doesn't ever contain that JSON object.

Comment: Why are you using POST at this stage? - you're not submitting a form.

Comment: post/get either way. This is only part of the process for this particular JSON object. The original logic was just have it post/get the Object I need as it would be rebuilding itself every 30-60 seconds via polling for new data. I suppose I could have the inital object render with the page then have it recreate with every poll of the object as I am ultimately looking to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.post` function does not actually return the return value of the success function, so you cannot just assign `myJSONobject` to it.

What you really want to do is

```
var myJSONobject;
$.post(uri, function(data){
    myJSONobject = data;
    // OR work with data here
});

// You cannot use myJSONobject right away
```

But be careful, you can't access `myJSONobject` right after calling `$.post`, you need to wait until the ajax call succeded.

Comment: I tried similar prior, though the way your doing it make sense, but what I was going to ask is one way I tried prior was chaining .complete() to the .post(), so I could fire off the function I want to work with the data in this particular part of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the Object right away before document.ready, use the jsonp technology, and load that script inside documents `<head>`. Or better load it at the end of the `<body>`, and the scripts that need it right after it.